# Getting a dictionary full path to specific key using reflection

Tags: c#

I have a situation where I have a nested `IDictionary`, like this;

```
class SomeObject {
    public IDictionary<string, IDictionary<string, decimal>> Entries { get; set; }
}
```

So, an object might look like this;

```
var o = new SomeObject {
   Entries = new ... {
      ["first"] = new ... {
         ["a"] = 1.0,
         ["b"] = 2.0
      },
      ["second"] = new ... {

      }
   }
};
```

I'm trying to figure out how to get the "path" to one of the nested keys as a collection of `string`s using a lambda expression. For example ...

```
class SomeFactory {
    public SomeFactory Use<T>(T entity) {
        this.Model = entity; return this;
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Get<TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<TProperty>>> selector) {
        var properties = ... // get list of properties from [selector] //
    }
}

var factory = new SomeFactory();
var list = factory.Use<SomeObject>(o).Get(n => n.Entries["first"]["b"]);
```

Where the result would be an `IEnumerable<string>` that had the values ...`{"Entries","first","b"}`.

Is this possible to do?

#### Use Case

The reason I am wanting to do this is because I'm working with a library that can issue out commands in a certain way using an object that looks like this (pseudo code);

```
class Patch {
   string Property;
   object Value;
   Patch[] Nested;
}
```

Each `Patch` can take the name of `1` property on an object deserialized from a given point. It will perform a very fast operation to it, considerably faster than loading the entire object from the database, updating it, and saving it again. This is important for a number of reasons at various parts of the program. (This is not an SQL database)

If a `nested` patch is given, it will not set the value on the top-level property, but instead find the top level property and use it as the launching point to execute the next `Patch` in the array. This process continues until it gets to the last one, whereupon it makes the change.

So in order to issue a patch to an `IDictionary`, the whole object graph needs to look something akin to ...

```
{
    "Property": "Entries",
    "Nested": [
        {
            "Property": "first",
            "Nested": [
                {
                    "Property": "b",
                    "Value": 7.0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This isn't a problem, but it's a bothersome graph to draw up each time. My thought was to make the entire process simpler by being able to construct this graph from just a lambda expression that found the desired destination on the `IDictionary` object; i.e `f(n => n["first"]["b"])`

Comment: Your question is unclear, are you trying to use reflection to call the dictionary, using an IEnumerable of strings, to store the keys?

Comment: Why do you need to use reflection on properties? Don't you just need to scan the dictionary indices?

Comment: Just to get the names of every property  and key leading to the desired point. There's a library I use that issues commands using property names, but it can only step through one at a time. To get to a nested dictionary key, you have to setup some annoying hoops, so I'm building methods to draw that up from an expression.

Comment: @Ciel, make all of the objects inherit from an interface so the first propert is always Entries, then just dump all of the keys for each. Entries.Keys,  Entries([0] => n).Value.Keys

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't believe that is an option. The names won't always be the same. The property name "Entries" was just an example.

Comment: Do all you objects have the same property name: "Entries"? Or is this unknown at compile time? EDIT: Ah, I think you just answered that.

Comment: @Ciel If its unknown at compile time, how are you going to build the lambda to begin with: `n => n.Entries["first"]["b"]`? `Entries` is known at compile time here. Your question is a little confusing.

Comment: Sorry. Misspoke. It is known, but this occurs to many types of objects with varying layout, shape, and properties. An interface won't work for it. I'm sorry that was confusing. I've been up all night working on this, so I'm a little dull right now.

Comment: @johnny5 I'm a bit confused by your suggestion, looking at it in more detail. I've never seen syntax quite like that. Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @Ciel, thats pseudo code its not real syntax

Comment: @Ciel,  You said this is going to happen for several different objects with different property names.  So there are a few ways to go about it.  1. Refactor your objects to have an interfaces, if you don't have access to the object, create an wrapper which will resolve all the types to finding the dictionary.  2. Iterate over the keys in both dictionaries to create mapping.  But it sounds like your trying to do something that probably has an easier solution,  Can you explain what this is for?

Comment: I'm a little confused as to how an interface would solve it. It's just not making sense to me. But, I have updated the question with more information as to why I want to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below fits your scenario above:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Get<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> selector)
{
    var list = new List<string>();

    Expression exp = (selector.Body as UnaryExpression).Operand as MethodCallExpression;

    while (exp is MethodCallExpression)
    {
        var call = exp as MethodCallExpression;

        var arg = call.Arguments[0].ToString();

        if(call.Arguments[0].Type == typeof(string))
        {
            arg = arg.Substring(1, arg.Length - 2);
        }

        list.Add(arg);

        exp = call.Object as Expression;
    }

    var member = exp as MemberExpression;

    list.Add(member.Member.Name);

    list.Reverse();

    return list;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var graph = Get<SomeObject>(o => o.Entries["first"]["b"]);

    foreach (var node in graph)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(node);
    }            

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Output is:

Entries

first

b